# How do you query an OData Collection of Enumerations?

Tags: odata

I have been searching for the definitive answer on this but can't seem to find it anywhere.  What I do know is that it's legal to create a Collection of the OData 4.0 Enumeration type.  I also know that the Olingo parser that we are using (4.2) allows us to query both an Enumeration or Collection of Enumeration using the 'has' keyword.  What I can't find, however, is any documentation that proves that this is actually a legitimate query. I also know that using OLingo and Microsoft parsers, that the any/all syntax that would generally be used for a Collection does not seem to work.  I would really appreciate any help figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

The OData version 4 spec says this about [logical operators](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398095): "Operands of collection, entity, and complex types are not supported in logical operators." `has` is one of the logical operators. Therefore, `has` is not supported on a collection of enumeration type. Furthermore, `has` is defined to operate on a single enumeration value, so it is not appropriate for querying a collection of enumeration values.

The spec also says that the [lambda operators](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398149) operate on "a navigation path that identifies a collection". If *navigation path* means a path that ends with a navigation property, then `any`/`all` can only be applied to a collection identified by a navigation property. Since collections of enumeration type are represented by structural properties, it follows that  `any`/`all` cannot be applied to collections of enumeration type. But this is conjecture, since the term *navigation path* is not defined in the spec.

In lieu of a collection of enumeration type, consider using an enumeration type that has the [IsFlags](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406397995) attribute set. You can definitely query such an enumeration using the `has` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the research. Based on what you are saying though, you can't actually query this using a filter?  That seems like a super huge oversight...

Comment: @Sergio: A flags enumeration provides a filterable alternative to a collection of enumeration flags. See my expanded answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it is limited to 64 elements as it's the implementation of a bit-flag field based on it's definition.  So, we are looking for a way to work with multi-valued enumerations that have more than 64 elements in them.

Comment: Consider defining an entity type rather than an enumeration type. I did this for an OData v2 service (before enums were part of the protocol). Let the entity consist of name, value, and display name. You can use either the name or the value as the key (or both if you want to support alternative keys). The display name opens the door to data-driven UI, and it can be localized per request.